Problem with date questions in Microsoft Form when creating a flow to Microsoft Lists
I've got a flow running to take responses and attachments from Microsoft Form into List. I am having an issue with the date questions. The flow is successful when I don't put the dates in the questions, but as soon as I do, I am getting this error: Action 'Create_item' failed: The 'inputs.parameters' of workflow operation 'Create_item' of type 'OpenApiConnection' is not valid. Error details: Input parameter 'item/Completethecostingstemplateforqu' is required to be of type 'String/uri'. The runtime value '"2024-09-04"' to be converted doesn't have the expected format 'String/uri'.
I'm assuming I need to convert these, but not sure where to make this conversion within the flow and what code to use. I have attached a screenshot of the flow.


Conversion should happen in action "Create item" or before.
Most probably, action is struggling with format. You could fix it by using formatDateTime(<date>, '<format>'). Once that is resolved, you might get wrong time due to mismatch of time zones - Power Automate works in UTC and you might be in other.
If timezone issue is relevant, both problems can be resolved by action "Convert Time Zone".

If timezone issue is not relevant, then try formatDateTime - input value for field item/Completethecostingstemplateforqu :

now most probably is outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/Completethecostingstemplateforqu'],
but should be formatDateTime(outputs('Get_response_details')?['body/Completethecostingstemplateforqu'])

Please verify the date-time format what you want get.
Command definition formatDateTime(<date>, '<format>')
Example formatDateTime(triggerOutputs()?['body/LaunchDate'], 'yyyy-MM-dd').
Use documentation for reference : link
Side note - SharePoint field names have limit of max 32 characters. Your field name is exactly 32 chars and look cut down at the end. Strongly advice to recreate new one (and replace existing) with shorter and more user friendly name. That will same some potential confusion in future. :)
